# Key Listener not working while using Image and Image Icon

Tags: java, image, animation, keylistener

So, I am using ImageIcon and Image to animate a character. So far my code makes it look like the character is running however for a reason that I can't figure out KeyListener is not working. I have been at this for a while and I am wondering what I am doing wrong. This is my code:
*Right now I took out moving up and down because I couldn't get side to side to work. velyY was going to be the change in y.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.MediaTracker;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import java.awt.Image;
    public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
    ImageIcon images[];
    int x = 100;
    int y = 5;
    int velX;
    int velY;
    int totalImages =3, currentImage = 0, animationDelay = 160;
    Timer animationTimer;
    public Main() {
    images = new ImageIcon[totalImages];
    images[0] = new ImageIcon("standing.png");
    images[1] = new ImageIcon("ready.png");
    images[2] = new ImageIcon("running.png");
    startAnimation();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics g2 = (Graphics) g;
    if (images[currentImage].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE){
    Image img =  images[currentImage].getImage();
    g2.drawImage(img, x, 407, null);
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % totalImages;
     }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    x+=velX;
    }

    public void right(){
    velX = 8;
    }
    public void left(){
    velX = -8;    
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    int code = arg0.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
    left();
     }
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
    right();
     }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
    }
    public void startAnimation() {
     if (animationTimer == null) {
      currentImage = 0;
     animationTimer = new Timer(animationDelay, this);
     animationTimer.start();
     } else if (!animationTimer.isRunning())
     animationTimer.restart();
     }

    public void stopAnimation() {
     animationTimer.stop();
      }  

     }//end class
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your `KeyListener` to your panel, if you want it to manage key events.

The second thing is that a `JPanel` is not focusable by default, so you have to make it focusable to receive key events.

In your `Main` constructor, just add :

```
setFocusable(true); // make your panel focusable
addKeyListener(this); // register the key listener
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem but now I have another. The picture only repeats once then stops from updating.

Comment: Did the animation work correctly before adding the key listener part ?